# Document and Window are not Defined Puppeteer Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, puppeteer

I'm having an issue where I'm running a automated chrome session using puppeteer in the back end of my electron app, but I keep getting the error document is undefined. Here is the code:

```
const isDone = await this.page.evaluate(async () => await this.autoScroll);

...

async autoScroll() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const timer = setInterval(() => {
                document.scrollingElement.scrollBy(0, 100);
                if (document.scrollingElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight >= document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve(true);
                }
            }, 230);
        });
    }
```

The code works an executes perfectly if I run it on its own in a different folder, but somehow it seems to error out when I run it in the app.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was transforming my code with babel. Puppeteer page.evaluate calls autoScroll.toString() which results in an incomplete string when used with babel. Instead it worked with:

```
const isDone = await this.page.evaluate(`(async() => {
                return new Promise(resolve => {
                    const timer = setInterval(() => {
                        document.scrollingElement.scrollBy(0, 100);
                        if (document.scrollingElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight >= document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight) {
                            clearInterval(timer);
                            resolve(true);
                        }
                    }, 230);
                });
             })()`);
```

Just put it in a string so there aren't any issues with the toString.